# how to take a derivative of an integral whose bound is a function of a different variable

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am following a proof where I got stuck at some point and to be honest, I'm little bit rusty when it comes to derivative and integral.

The function that I am interested is $ z = x F(x) -  \int_{y=0}^{x} y f(y) \,dy $ where $x$ is a random variable and $F(x)$ is its cumulative distribution function. For simplicity, this is only a small portion of function $z$.

When we take the derivative of $Z$ with respect to $x$, in the first part, we apply the chain rule as:

$ F(x) + x f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the density function. For the second part, I think we should use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the proof reaches the following:

$\frac{dz}{dx} = F(x) + x f(x) - x f(x)$ which ends up as $F(x)$. My question is that how we obtain $xf(x)$ when taking the derivative of $\int_{y=0}^{x} y f(y) \,dy$ wrt $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{y = 0}^{x} yf(y) dy = xf(x)$$

As in general we have have for a continuous function $f(t)$ on a closed interval domain (where $x$ and $a$ belong to this domain so we are assured integrability):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{t = a}^{x} f(t) dt = f(x)$$

Comment: I cannot find this equation in the fundemantal theorem of calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#

Comment: @ball_jan It is a form of the first fundamental theorem of calculus, in particular, remark by the archetypal equation: $\int_{t = a}^x f(t)dt = F(x) - F(a)$, so it follows then $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{t = a}^x f(t)dt = \frac{d}{dx}(F(x) - F(a)) = f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

If $z =   \int_{y=0}^{x} y f(y) \,dy,$
the derivative definition  is  $$ \dfrac{dz}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}
\dfrac{\int_{y=0}^{x+\Delta x} y f(y) \,dy-\int_{y=0}^{x} y f(y) \,dy}{\Delta x}
 =\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\dfrac{\int_{y=x}^{x+\Delta x} y f(y) \,dy}{\Delta x}
=xf(x). $$